# Connect to a secured webservice with the Savon rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I'm trying to use Savon to connect to a webservice and can't figure out how to make it work.

let's say I have a webservice: https://wwww.service.com:16778/services/2.0/ (no wsdl provided)
the service provided sent me a .p12 file and a password required to connect

How do I implement this?
What's the use of the namespace?

I wrote something like the following but doesn't seem to work

```
  client = Savon.client do
    endpoint end_point          
    namespace "https://wwww.service.com:16778"
    ssl_verify_mode :none
    ssl_cert_file OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(cert_file), 'password')
    ssl_cert_key_file Rails.root + "lib/certificates/CC0000007015_500.p12"
end
```

thanks for your help